# Много паттернов и одна строка

Tags: python

Приветствую,

Есть много regex шаблонов и одна строка. Ищу разумный способ определить, какой из шаблонов совпадает со строкой.

В данный момент прогоняю строку по циклу из шаблонов и проверяю, совпадает ли она со шаблоном.

```
import re
patterns = [ (re.compile("^/upload/test/$"), "upload"),
             (re.compile("^/download/test/$"), "download"),
             (re.compile("^/test/$"), "test")]
string = "/test/"

for pattern in patterns:
    if pattern[0].match(string):
        print pattern[1]
```

Есть ли способ лучше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас выбран вполне годный способ. При беглом прочтении джанговсокого [урлресолвера](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L209) вроде становиться понятно, что у них все так же как у вас.

Не сильно относиться к делу но это

```
patterns = [ (re.compile("^/upload/test/$"), "upload"),
             ... ]
```

можно поменять на

```
patterns = ( (re.compile("^/upload/test/$"), "upload"),
             ... )
```

Вроде вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630/are-tuples-more-efficient-than-lists-in-python) доказано что tuple(простите, не знаю как перевести) быстрее list в инициации и итерации.

Comment: Ну раз так буду этот способ и использовать.